# Setting up Mechanize Phantomjs

Tags: perl, phantomjs, mechanize

I am running into an issue.
I want to use WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS. I have set it up as follow.
1. Installed Strawberry and WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS Module
2.Downloaded PhantomJS zip, extracted it and set the path for phantomjs executable.
3. created a sample script as follow:

```
BEGIN{
$ENV{HTTPS_PROXY} = 'http://myproxyserver:port';
$ENV{HTTP_PROXY}  = 'http://myproxyserver:port';
}
use WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS;
use Data::Dumper;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS->new();
$mech->get('http://google.com');
print Dumper $mech->content();
```

but when I execute this script I get the following error:

```
Selenium server did not return proper status at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 395.
```

whats that I am missing.
I assume that this WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS starts phantomjs from path specified in environment.

Edit:
I uninstalled WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS and tried installing again but got following output:

```
t/00-load.t ................... ok
t/49-mech-get-file.t .......... # Testing with     C:\bin\phantomjs\phantomjs.exe
Selenium server did not return proper status at  C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 395.
# Looks like your test exited with 9 before it could output anything.
t/49-mech-get-file.t .......... Dubious, test returned 9 (wstat 2304, 0x900)
Failed 12/12 subtests
t/49-mech-nav.t ............... # Testing with  C:\bin\phantomjs\phantomjs.exe
Selenium server did not return proper status at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 395.
```

Then as suggested I modified C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib\LWP\Protocol\http.pm as follow

```
   sub _new_socket
{
    my($self, $host, $port, $timeout) = @_;

    # IPv6 literal IP address should be [bracketed] to remove
    # ambiguity between ip address and port number.
    if ( ($host =~ /:/) && ($host !~ /^\[/) ) {
      #$host = "[$host]";
      $host  = '127.0.0.1';
    }
```

and again issued command
    cpan WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS
but same output again.

Comment: Somebody posted [the same issue](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1104241) on PerlMonks last year. Does [natalie_g's solution](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1148279) work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the help but it did not make any difference.

Comment: What did not make any difference? Please [edit] your question to show specifically what you tried and what errors you got after trying it.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please take a look at issue.